# Prisma post deployment issues

Tags: deployment, server, graphql, prisma

I'm trying to make my Prisma post deployment hook work but it for some reason it doesn't generate the `prisma.graphql` file

Has anyone experienced this before? I followed the official guidelines for this.

prisma.yml

```
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
endpoint: ${env:PRISMA_ENDPOINT}
secret: ${env:PRISMA_SECRET}
hooks:
  post-deploy:
    - graphql get-schema --project prisma
```

.graphqlconfig.yml

```
projects:
  app:
    schemaPath: "src/schema.graphql"
    extensions:
      endpoints:
        default: "http://localhost:4444"
  prisma:
    schemaPath: "src/generated/prisma.graphql"
    extensions:
      prisma: prisma.yml
```

my endpoint is the demo server's endpoint on prisma's website

The result i'm getting when i run the deploy command is:

```
post-deploy:
Running graphql get-schema --project prisma ✔
```

Comment: Can you show me your package.json file?

Answer (score 3):

here is a workaround that will generate prisma.graphql and automatically update it after prisma deploy

```
 generate:
   - generator: graphql-schema
     output: ./src/generated/
hooks:
  post-deploy:
    - graphql get-schema -p prisma
    - prisma generate
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running `graphql get-schema --project prisma` as a post-deploy hook, it's not showing the errors for that command. Try to put it as a npm script in package.json and run. See what's the error in there. Most probably the issue will be a mismatch of `graphql` package version. If that's the problem, add the following snippet to your `package.json` file and re-run `npm install` or `yarn install`:

```
"resolutions": {
  "graphql": "^14.0.2"
},
```